# describe relationship between two categorical variables?

Tags: r

I have a table called "smoke", containing 300 rows (one row for each subject) and two variables ("group" and "race"). Group takes the values "smoker", "non-smoker" or "quit" and race takes the values "White", "Black", "Hispanic", "Asian".

I want to write a single line of R code which will yield an appropriate description of the relationship between smoking group and race.

Comment: This isn't a very good specific programming question - nor are you demonstrating much in the way of research effort (what have you tried? why aren't you satisfied with the results?), which can sometimes help in the case of an otherwise low quality question. Do you want a table to give cross tabulations? Use `table()`. Do you want to fit a model, maybe a multinomial GLM? If you don't know what you want as a result, then you need to figure that out first.

Answer (score 1):

The typical statistical test for independence of association of two categorical variables where neither of them has what I would consider a natural ordering would be a chi-squared test for independence.

```
with(dataset, chisq.test( smoke, Group) )
```

To look at the actual values just:

```
with(dataset, table( smoke, Group) )
# OR
with(dataset, prop.table(table( smoke, Group)))
```